# How to merge SQL queries to use result first one?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to merge the below 2 MySQL statements to return just one result.

This first query returns a list of `companyId`'s & `name`'s:

```
SELECT gap.user_companies.companyId, gap.companies.name
FROM gap.user_companies
INNER JOIN gap.users
ON gap.user_companies.userId = gap.users.userId
INNER JOIN gap.companies
ON gap.user_companies.companyId = gap.companies.companyId
WHERE gap.users.username = 'tester';
```

The next query that I'm running returns a list of dates, but they need to use the `companyId` value from the above query.

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT creationdate, meetingdate FROM reports
WHERE reportId IN (
    SELECT reportId FROM report_companies 
    WHERE companyId = 123
)
ORDER BY creationdate;
```

So I need to combine the above queries to return `name` from the **COMPANIES** table, as well as `creationdate` & `meetingdate` from the **REPORTS** table.

Belwo is some pseudo-code to help explain what the catch is:

The second query will need to use the `companyId` result of the first query.
The first query will return multiple records, so I need to update my `WHERE companyId = 123` to something like

`WHERE companyId IN (the companyId part of the first query's result)`

Can someone please show how to merge these?

Comment: Join the two queries.

Comment: You seem to know how to embed subqueries into each other, so what prevents you from using the 1st query as subquery in the 2nd query? (Although I would rewrite most of these as joins)

Comment: Hi @Shadow, that's what I have done also, but I need to return the `name` as part of the result also, so that's why I'm trying to write them as joins

Comment: What have you done so far to rewrite the queries as joins and what did you get stuck with?

Comment: Hi @Shadow, I've updated my first query above to use joins. I'm working on the second query now & will update the question once that's complete

Comment: @Shadow, is it possible to do this with just joins and no sub queries?